# Android 12 Canvas drawPoint() - Paint contains alpha which can't be removed

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, paint

after setting targetSDK=31 and testing my app I stumbled over this weird behaviour, maybe you know the solution

my code looks like this:

```
    private val foregroundPaint: Paint by lazy {
        Paint().apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            color = Color.BLACK
        }
    }
...
        val barcodeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            width,
            height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )

        val canvas = Canvas(barcodeBitmap)
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)

        // Draw black pixels on bitmap
        for ((x, i) in (xLeft until xRight).withIndex()) {
            for ((y, j) in (yTop until yBottom).withIndex()) {
                if (bm[i, j]) {
                    canvas.drawPoint(
                        x.toFloat(),
                        y.toFloat(),
                        foregroundPaint
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        return barcodeBitmap
```

on Android 12 drawPoint contains some alpha Channel which can't be removed, I already tried with

```
   private val foregroundPaint: Paint by lazy {
        Paint().apply {
            alpha = 255
            color = Color.BLACK
        }
    }
```

but unfortunately it didn't work...

when i call drawPoint() 2 times, it's real black, but i think there must be a better solution to this problem.

here are the screenshots of my generated bitmaps

[image: Android 12:]

[image: Android 11:]

As you can see on Android 12 the Black Color is clearly brighter.

Every hint is welcome!

## Short Update

instead of drawing the code onto the canvas I draw it directly onto the Bitmap

```
barcodeBitmap.setPixel(
   x,
   y,
   Color.BLACK,
)
```

now it's working as expected.

if you get here and know a better solution, please let me know :)

Comment: `alpha = 50` or `color = Color.argb(50, 0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: unfortunately no, it just makes the black part even lighter. my goal was to display it in the same black on android 12 like android 11 without alpha

Comment: Are you sure they have the same brightness? I would try using a shader or a ColorFilter. ColorFilter is much easier.

Comment: yes brightness is exactly the same. could you please give me an example how you would use the ColorFilter?

Comment: One more thing, have you tried setting `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`? This will force to use the cpu for drawings.

Comment: yes i have tried it but didn't work. I really don't know whats different on Android 12, but i found a workaround, instead of drawing the pixels on the canvas i draw them directly into the bitmap


barcodeBitmap.setPixel(
                        x + BARCODE_PADDING_HORIZONTAL,
                        y + BARCODE_PADDING_VERTICAL,
                        Color.BLACK,
                    )


now they have the correct Color

thanks for your help :)

Comment: Try Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0) isntead of Color.BLACK, some devices add some transparency to the colors.xml @color/white (and sometimes some yellow here) and @color/black so it blend with the layout but i'm not sure if it reflect in the constants provided with the API

Comment: Plus your pixel paint shouldnt have ```isAntiAlias = true``` you should use only when drawing curves

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @marcos, i tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work either. isAntiAliasing was a left over from playing around. it's already removed. there has to be some change in Android 12, the same device with Android 11 showed the color correct, after updating there was this slight transparency.